# MongoDB update in PHP: update one variable on multiple ids(which represents as variable)

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, sql-update

I need to update a textual label into the MongoDB database based on the selected checkboxes from the last page in PHP.

For example,

I select 5 checkboxes and enter a textual label in the textbox. In the next page, I need to write the update statement to update the textual label into the database for the 5 selected checkboxes. It means that the 5 selected checkboxes'paths should have the same textual label updated into the database. The database does not include a textual label attribute.notes: selectedIds = selected checkboxes'paths; clusters do not have textLabel, so I have to create here?

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://username:password@localhost:xxxx/db_name?authSource=db_name'); (the $manger works, it includes the information of username, passwork, db_name, and local_host). 
$updateResult = array();
  foreach($selectedImages as $selectedImages){
$result = $manager->update(
  array("filename.anonPath" => $selectedImages),
  array("clusters_r37_mcs100.textLabel" => $textLabel),
  array_push($updateResult,$result);
);
}
print_r("$updateResult");
```

**I have one questions:**

The terminal does not display anything whether I succeed to update or not. However, when I check in the MongoDB database, I did not see any textLabel update.

Thank you.

Comment: *"I have two questions:"* - Then you actually should not be asking "two" questions in the **one question** format of Stack Overflow without posting a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). And for your "first question", you really need to show the actual error text. But I suspect you only installed the core PHP driver and not the [PHPLib driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/), which is what you are supposed to be using.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thak you for the remainder of the format. I have the code. Here is my new issue.

Comment: `MongoDB\Driver` is the **wrong** driver. That's the core driver as I stated days ago now. Don't bother editing the question. Go to the link I gave you in the comment, read it and install the **correct** driver and rewrite your code to use that.